# How do I select multiple images using cn1 file chooser

Tags: codenameone

I am creating a mobile app where I need users to be able to select multiple images. I am using the cn1 lib file chooser but I am only able to select one Image. How can I select multiple images. Here is the code I use to select the image.

```
chooseImage.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                animateImage.show();
                if (FileChooser.isAvailable()){
                    FileChooser.showOpenDialog(".jpg,.png,.gif", e2->{
                        String file = (String)e2.getSource();
                        if (file == null){
                            animateImage.add("No File Was Selected");
                            animateImage.revalidate();
                        }else {
                            String extension = null;
                            if (file.lastIndexOf(".") > 0){
                                extension = file.substring(file.lastIndexOf(".")+1);
                            }
                            if ("txt".equals(extension)){
                                FileSystemStorage fs = FileSystemStorage.getInstance();
                                try {
                                    InputStream fis = fs.openInputStream(file);
                                    animateImage.addComponent(new SpanLabel(Util.readToString(fis)));
                                } catch (Exception ex) {
                                    Log.e(ex);
                                }
                            }else{
                                try{
                                    Image image = URLImage.createImage((String)e2.getSource());
                                    animateImage.add(image);
                                }catch (IOException e){
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                                //animateImage.add("Selected file "+file);
                            }
                        }
                        animateImage.revalidate();
                    });
                    /*try{
                        Image image = URLImage.createImage((String)evt.getSource());
                        animateImage.add(image);
                    }catch (IOException e){
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }*/

                }
            }
        });
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There is no support for that in the cn1lib. You can fork the cn1lib and add support for it manually by changing the native code in the lib.

This isn't supported currently in the standard Codename One API, there is an RFE to add it here: https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/issues/2383